# Prop value isn't updating in child component Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue-component, vue-router

I'm adding a way for the parent `App.vue` tell all child components to close every modal you have open and for any given child to tell the parent to hide the overlay if someone clicks on the main app div. So for example if the services page has a modal open to view some details, an overlay will be active that is set in the parent `App.vue` component, and if I click anywhere outside of the modal, the modal will close and the child will tell the parent to close the overlay. I have it setup this way so that it's something globally available and not isolated to a single component.

```
<template>
  <div id="app" v-cloak :class="{'overlay-layer' : overlay.active}" v-on:click="close($event)">

    <Header/>

    <transition>
      <router-view v-on:overlay="overlay.active = $event" :closeAllModals="overlay.close"/>
    </transition>

    <Footer/>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from '@/components/header/Header.vue';
import Footer from '@/components/footer/Footer.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    Header,
    Footer
  },
  props: {
    closeAllModals: Boolean
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      overlay: { active: false, close: false }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    close(e) {
      if (this.overlay.active && e.toElement.id === 'app') {
        this.overlay = {
          active: false,
          close: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The problem is that this only executes once, so for example in the services page I have:

```
import Header from '@/components/header/Header.vue';
import Footer from '@/components/footer/Footer.vue';

export default {
  name: 'services',
  components: {
    Header,
    Footer
  },
  props: {
    closeAllModals: Boolean
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      overlay: false,
      activeMember: Object,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setActiveMember(member, open) {
      this.activeMember = member;
      if (open) {
        this.activeMember.active = true;
        this.overlay = true;
      } else {
        this.activeMember.active = false;
        this.overlay = false;
      }
      this.$emit('overlay', this.overlay);
      this.$forceUpdate();
    },
  watch: {
    closeAllModals: function() {
      this.activeMember.active = false;
      this.overlay = false;
      this.$forceUpdate();
      console.log('runs once');
    }
  }
};
```

So this works, but only works the first time. The prop only sends the updated value to the child only once. I've tried watching the prop in the child and using forceUpdate too but it isn't working. How do I make this run every single time?

Comment: Can you create [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue)?

Comment: its better to create https://codesandbox.io/ but one thing I can say is your way is un-necessarily complex for such basic task.

Comment: Thanks @Lahori How else would you do this ?

Comment: one approach could be to make overlay wrap the modal in modal component. use position: fixed, z-index: highest & you should be good.

Comment: @EdgarQuintero you could investigate more here https://bulmanent.surge.sh/#/Modals

Comment: a global eventbus could be another option https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Comment: Awesome thanks, tried the eventbus way and it works. Do you want to post the answer? @Gowri

Comment: sure will do thanks for the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global event bus could help when components have to talk to each other across different parent/child levels. Below is a good write up on that:

https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus

Note: but be sure to use it only when necessary and remove the listeners in `beforeDestroy` life cycle of the component